# Given just a speed (or kinetic energy) distribution plot of particles, is it possible to calculate their entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

What can you deduce about the entropy of a substance by seeing the plot of the particle speed frequency in the material? I'm wondering how the two are related and how additional information you need to calculate entropy given the "equation" for the plot and how you might go about doing it.

[image: Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution]

Comment: Are these particles inside a box?

Comment: Sorry, yes, they are!

Comment: How much statistical mechanics do you know?

Comment: As much as an undergraduate Thermodynamics sequence teaches